# Selecionando uma coluna a partir de um laço condicional em um dataframe do pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Eu tenho um dataframe do pandas com cinco linhas 3 três colunas. Eu quero criar uma função onde o meu código retorne quais colunas o valor da última linha seja maior que a primeira linha. No exemplo do meu código eu quero que ele me gere uma lista com o nome da coluna 'Temp01'. Eu me atrapalhei na hora de criar o if/else para verificar as colunas cuja ultima linha seja maior que a primeira. Abaixo segue meu código:

```
#Importa as Bibliotecas Pandas e Numpy
import pandas as pd

#Cria do Dataframe
df0 = pd.DataFrame({'Temp01':[10,20,30,40,15],'Temp02':[50,60,70,70,45],'Temp03':[80,90,100,100,75]})

#Separa Colunas cuja ultima linha seja maior que a primeira
teste =[]#Lista c o nome de cada coluna do Dataframe df0

for column in df0.columns:

#df0.column[-1] para pegar a ultima linha de cada coluna 
#df0.column[0] para pegar a primeira linha de cada coluna

  if df0.column[-1]> df0.column[0]:
    text = column
    teste.append(text)
  else:
    pass
print(teste)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Importa as Bibliotecas Pandas e Numpy
import pandas as pd

#Cria do Dataframe
df0 = pd.DataFrame({'Temp01':[10,20,30,40,15],'Temp02':[50,60,70,70,45],'Temp03':[80,90,100,100,75]})

#Separa Colunas cuja ultima linha seja maior que a primeira
teste =[]#Lista c o nome de cada coluna do Dataframe df0

def Ultimo_Maior_Valor(p1,p2):
    '''Função retorna Verdadeiro ou Falso se ultimo valor é maior ou não'''
    if (p1 < p2):
        return True
    else:
        return False

for column in df0.columns:

    #Head pega n primeiro valor
    #Tail pega n ultimo valor
    p1 = int(df0[column].head(1))
    p2 = int(df0[column].tail(1))

  #Se o retorno for True, ele entra no if
    if Ultimo_Maior_Valor( p1, p2 ):
        teste.append(column)

print('Coluna(s) com último valor maior que o primeiro:')
print(teste)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]